# DRY: Minimizing repeated code in Java

Tags: java, dry

I'm writing a method in Java:

```
List<Foo> computeFooList(/* arguments */)
{
    /* snip */
}
```

I'd like to write a second method with exactly the same logic, but a different return type:

```
List<String> computeStringList(/* same arguments */)
{
    /* snip */
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a non-hackish way to minimize the amount of repeated code between the two methods. The **only** logical difference between the two is that, when adding an object to the list that's returned, the first method adds the acutal `Foo`:

```
List<Foo> computeFooList(/* arguments */)
{
    List<Foo> toReturn = ...
    ...
    for (Foo foo : /* some other list of Foo */)
    {
        if (/* some condition */)
        {
            toReturn.add(foo);
        }
    }
    ...
    return toReturn;
}
```

and the second adds a `String` representation of the `Foo`:

```
List<String> computeStringList(/* same arguments */)
{
    List<String> toReturn = ...
    ...
    for (Foo foo : /* some other list of Foo */)
    {
        if (/* some condition */)
        {
            toReturn.add(foo.toString());
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In reality, it's not quite *that* simple. I don't want to add a `Foo` to `toReturn` unless I'm absolutely sure it belongs there. As a result, that decision is made per-`foo` using helper functions. With two different versions of the methods, I'd need different versions of the helper functions as well - in the end, I'd be writing two sets of nigh-identical methods, but for one little generic type.

---

Can I write a single method which contains all of the decision-making logic, but can generate **either a `List<Foo>` or a `List<String>`**? Is it possible to do this without using raw `List` types (bad practice in generics land!) or wildcard `List<?>` types? I imagine an implementation that looks something like this:

```
List<Foo> computeFooList(/* args */)
{
    return computeEitherList(/* args */, Foo.class);
}

List<String> computeStringList(/* args */)
{
    return computeEitherList(/* args */, String.class);
}

private List<???> computeEitherList(/* args */, Class<?> whichType)
{
    /* snip */
}
```

**Is there any nice, elegant way to do this?** I've been playing around with generic methods, but I can't see a way to do this. Even mucking about with reflection hasn't gotten me anywhere (maybe I need something like [`TypeToken`](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener)? ...eww).

Comment: You might be interested in this new stackexchange site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you externalize transformation logic into a separate strategy (such as Guava's `Function<F, T>`):

```
public <T> List<T> computeList(/* arguments */, Function<? super Foo, T> f) {
     List<T> toReturn = ...     ...     
     for (Foo foo : /* some other list of Foo */) {
         if (/* some condition */) {
             toReturn.add(f.apply(foo));
         }
     }
     return toReturn;
}
```

computeFooList:

```
computeList(..., Functions.identity());
```

computeStringList:

```
computeList(..., Functions.toStringFunction());
```

Comment: This definitely looks promising. Let me play around with this.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I was already using Guava, too. I need to dig deeper into it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a "SearchFilter" interface and a "FilterAdapter" abstract class that I use in ways similar to this.  The decision logic can be made independently and in a generic way from actually adding things to the return list.  I would be checking each Foo and saying "true" include it or "false" exclude it.

```
public interface SearchFilter<T>
{
    public boolean include(T item);
    public Collection<T> apply(Collection<T> items);
}
```

A filter can be applied to an existing collection with the `apply()` method, returning a new collection that only includes the desired items.

```
newCollection = myfilter.apply(originalItems);
```

This may not be useful to you, but the `include()` concept should work well to avoid repeating the decision logic.

You could have a `FooFilter extends FilterAdapter<Foo>` (I also instantiate these anonymously in-line sometimes) which provides an implementation of `include`

```
public FooFilter extends FilterAdapter<Foo>
{
    public boolean include(Foo item)
    {
        if (item.isInvalid()) return false;
        // or any other complex logic you want
        return item.hasGoodThings();
    }
}
```

The `apply()` method is almost always just loop over the initial collection and test `include` so it has a default implementation in my `FilterAdapter` but can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little ugly, but I think this might work:

```
List<Foo> computeFooList(/* args */) {
    return computeEitherList(/* args */, Foo.class);
}

List<String> computeStringList(/* args */) {
    return computeEitherList(/* args */, String.class);
}

private <T> List<T> computeEitherList(/* args */, Class<T> whichType) {
    List<T> rval = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Foo foo : listOfFoo) {
        // process foo

        if (whichType.equals(Foo.class)) {
            rval.add(whichType.cast(foo));
        }
        else if (whichType.equals(String.class)) {
            rval.add(whichType.cast(foo.toString()));
        }
        else {
            throw new SomeException("Cannot compute list for type " + whichType);
        }
    }
    return rval;
}
```